# Catching RUNTIME Error of a executable executed by python's POPEN function of subprocess module

Tags: python, shell, runtime-error, subprocess, stderr

I am writing a python script which compiles and runs a C/C++ code.
I want to capture **runtime errors**.
Eg: Nzecv, Segmentation fault, Fragmentation Error etc

I am using following command to execute the compiled file:

```
process = Popen( exec_path , stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell= False) 
(output, error) = process.communicate(testCase)
```

I have tried few programs with runtime errors, but the errors ***arent reflected in stderr***.
After some research i found that stderr reads from *return value of program*.
And in C and mostly all other programs, main returns custom ("return 0;") value not the error signal.

Is it possible to ***catch runtime error signal?*** How should i go about implementing it?

EDIT: Can runtime error signal be captured by Terminal? HOW?
If yes, ill run the corresponding shell script through python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to catch runtime error signal? How should i go about implementing it?

To find out whether the child process is killed by a signal, you could inspect [`process.returncode`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode):

> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal
>   N (Unix only).

Note: if you want to provide a custom handler for a signal in the child process, you could call `signal.signal()` in `preexec_fn`, see [code example that shows how to restore default signal handler using `prexec_fn`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083141/4279)