# 'yes' reporting error with subprocess communicate()

Tags: python, linux, shell, command-line, subprocess

I am using the following function to run a command in Python:

```
def run_proc(cmd):
    child = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = child.communicate()
    returncode = child.returncode
    return stdout, stderr, returncode
```

It has always been working fine, however now I'm trying to use the `yes` program to pipe output to stdin. The command I'm trying to run is the following:

```
yes '' | apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" dist-upgrade
```

but I believe it could be substituted with a general example, like:

```
yes | head -3 | cat
```

My problem is that if I try to run any command which has `yes |` in it, the above subprocess.Popen will contain the error messages:

```
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
yes: write error
```

For me it seems that the piping still works, as can be seen from `yes | head -3 | cat`'s answer: `y y y`.

I have the following questions:

1. Is the yes piping still functional, even though yes reports error?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: here's [some info about `yes`, `SIGPIPE`, and `EPIPE`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20573282/4279)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is that `subprocess` module [before Python 3.2+ doesn't restore `SIGPIPE` signal handler to default action](http://bugs.python.org/issue1652). That is why you get `EPIPE` write error instead.

In Python 3.2+

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output("yes | head -3", shell=True)
b'y\ny\ny\n'
```

`yes` is killed by `SIGPIPE` when `head` exits.

In Python 2:

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> check_output("yes | head -3", shell=True)
yes: standard output: Broken pipe
yes: write error
'y\ny\ny\n'
```

`yes` got `EPIPE` write error. It is safe to ignore the error. [It communicates the same information as `SIGPIPE`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20624315/4279).

To workaround the problem, you could emulate `restore_signals` in Python 2 using `preexec_fn` parameter :

```
>>> from subprocess import check_output
>>> import signal
>>> def restore_signals(): # from http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/768722b2ae0a/
...     signals = ('SIGPIPE', 'SIGXFZ', 'SIGXFSZ')
...     for sig in signals:
...         if hasattr(signal, sig):
...            signal.signal(getattr(signal, sig), signal.SIG_DFL)
... 
>>> check_output("yes | head -3", shell=True, preexec_fn=restore_signals)
'y\ny\ny\n'
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I appreciate the fact that this doesn't require changing your code if you are porting over from shell scripts.

Answer (score 3):

the other question answers the why ... I'll try and give you a work around

could you not do something like

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, 
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

for i in range(10):  #send 10 y's
    time.sleep(1) # 1 second apart
    proc.stdin.write("y") #you may also need to send a newline ...

print proc.communicate()
```

see below (I didnt bother with the delay since head isnt really doing much)

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen("head -3",
...                          shell = True,
...                          stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
...                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
...                          stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> for i in range(10):
...    proc.stdin.write("y\n")
...
>>> proc.communicate()
('y\ny\ny\n', '')
```

Comment: This is cool, but for commands more complicated then 'yes' it might require rewriting all the functionality in Python, which might or might not be the preferred solution.

Answer (score 2):

Saying:

```
yes | head -3
```

causes `head` to send a `SIGPIPE` to `yes` once it's done reading 3 lines of input, i.e. it'd send a signal to terminate `yes`.

```
$ yes | head -3
y
y
y
$ echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"
141 0
```

The solution would be to avoid a `SIGPIPE`!

Comment: It is the opposite: the issues is that [`SIGPIPE` signal is *trapped* in Python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22083141/4279)