# Python subprocess.Popen blocks with shell and pipe

Tags: python

Running the following command: `yes | head -1`, from the shell, outputs `y`. Using python's subprocess module to call it with a shell hangs indefinitely:

```
import subprocess

arg = "yes | head -1"
process = subprocess.Popen(arg,
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
)

print "Command started: %d" % process.pid
r = process.communicate()
print "Command ended: %s %s" % r
```

Killing the process exogenously using `kill` does not help, nor does making the child process it's session leader using `preexec_fn=os.setsid`.

What could be causing this behavior, and is there anyway I can prevent it?

I'm running python 2.7.3 and my `/bin/sh` is `GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)`

Comment: use `"Command ended: %r" % (r,)` because `r` is a tuple.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Python 2.7 on Ubuntu. It works ok +/- [the expected "write" error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22077881/4279).

Comment: thanks, that link was enough to solve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that this is caused due to a known issue with python not resetting signal handlers before exec in the `subprocess` module.

This is the same problem that causes ['yes' reporting error with subprocess communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22077881/4279), except with GNU `yes`, the EPIPE returned by a write causes the program to abort, whereas with BSD `yes` (which is used on OS X as far as I can tell), the return code of the write is not checked, so without a `SIGPIPE`, `yes` will not terminate.

It can be fixed by backporting the `reset_signals` code, as in the above linked question:

```
def restore_signals():
    signals = ('SIGPIPE', 'SIGXFZ', 'SIGXFSZ')
    for sig in signals:
        if hasattr(signal, sig):
            signal.signal(getattr(signal, sig), signal.SIG_DFL)
```

then setting `preexec_fn=restore_signals` in the `Popen` call.