# Why subprocess does not terminate with Python 2.7 only?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a code that spawns a process with `subprocess.Popen`:

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError, Popen, PIPE
cmd="while true; do echo 123; done | grep -m1 123"
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```

When I run it with Python 3.9.2, it terminates immediately as expected. However when I run it with Python 2.7 it hangs. It seems that Python 2.7 waits for shell infinite loop to terminate but it will not terminate ever. Can I make this code terminate under Python 2.7 as well?

Comment: It's not immediately obvious to me that it should return.  Popen started a shell process.  That process is still running, even though `grep` has closed the `stdout` handle.

Comment: When `grep` terminates it should also terminate  `while true` loop. This can be observed in bash interactive shell. This is what happens in Python 3.9.2 as I see, but not in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found related question [Python subprocess.Popen blocks with shell and pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23064636/72178) for Python 2.7. The problem is that in Python 2.7 `SIGPIPE` signal is ignored by default and therefore `while true` loop ignores the fact that `grep` terminates on first match. There is unresolved Python issue for this https://bugs.python.org/issue1652. On Python 3 there is an extra parameter `restore_signals=True` for `subprocess.Popen` and therefore the code above works as is. For Python 2.7 it can be modified to restore `SIGPIPE` signal this way:

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError, Popen, PIPE
import signal

def restore_signals():
    signals = ('SIGPIPE', 'SIGXFZ', 'SIGXFSZ')
    for sig in signals:
        if hasattr(signal, sig):
            signal.signal(getattr(signal, sig), signal.SIG_DFL)

cmd="while true; do echo 123; done | grep -m1 123"
proc = Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, preexec_fn=restore_signals)
out, err = proc.communicate()
```