# Subproces.popen - slave write failed: Broken pipe; aborting

Tags: python, subprocess

TLDR: stuck with this https://code.google.com/archive/p/byte-unixbench/issues/1

Trying to run UnixBench using `subprocess.popen()` while capturing output and printing it out in realtime.

This is the subroutine I've come up with:

```
def run_and_print(command, cwd=None, catch_stderr = False):
    if catch_stderr:
        err_pipe = subprocess.PIPE
    else:
        err_pipe = subprocess.STDOUT

    p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=1, cwd=cwd, stderr=err_pipe)
    r = ''
    while True:
        if catch_stderr:
            out = p.stderr.read(1)
        else:
            out = p.stdout.read(1)
        if out == "" and p.poll() != None:
            break
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        r += out

    return r
```

It works just fine for all the purposes except for UnixBench. Unixbench just dies after a while:

```
unixbench = run_and_print(['./Run'])
```

> ...
>
> 1 x Pipe Throughput  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
>
> 1 x Pipe-based Context Switching  1 2 3 4
>
> ---
>
> Run: "Pipe-based Context Switching": slave write failed: Broken pipe; aborting

Google didn't help much. The only meaningful result I've got is https://code.google.com/archive/p/byte-unixbench/issues/1 and suggest solution to create a java app won't work for me as I need to run the script with as few dependencies as possible.

I'll be thankful for any solution or a workaround. The system I'm testing this on is Ubuntu 14.04.4 x64

Comment: Probably won't help, but did you try `p.communicate()`? One possible hack: don't try to capture the output in Python; instead, run the command by redirecting stderr and stdout to different text files. Then read those files via Python.

Comment: @FMc  Great idea about writing to files, not sure how to print stdout in realtime if it's redirected to a file. 

How would you suggest using p.communicate()? It was my understanding that with `communicate` I won't get any output until the process is done.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user1556912, your understanding is correct, you cannot use communicate if you want the output immediately.

Comment: related: [Run command and get its stdout, stderr separately in near real time like in a terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31953436/4279) and [Displaying subprocess output to stdout and redirecting it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25750468/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug is related to ['yes' reporting error with subprocess communicate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22077881/4279) which provides the fix: reenable `SIGPIPE` signal in the child process using `preexec_fn` (or use Python 3).

---

Unrelated: your code can deadlock if `catch_stderr` is true and `p.stderr` and `p.stdout` are not perfectly in sync.

Otherwise `catch_stderr` has no effect (ignoring buffering): your code captures stderr regardless. You could simplify it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from shutil import copyfileobj
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

def run_and_print(command, cwd=None):
    p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=-1, cwd=cwd,
              preexec_fn=restore_signals)
    with p.stdout:
        tee = Tee()
        copyfileobj(p.stdout, tee)        
    return p.wait(), tee.getvalue()
```

where `Tee()` is a file-like object that writes to two places: to stdout and to `StringIO()`:

```
import sys
from io import BytesIO

class Tee:
   def __init__(self):
       self.file = BytesIO()
   def write(self, data):
       getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write(data)
       self.file.write(data)
   def getvalue(self):
       return self.file.getvalue()
```

where [`restore_signals()` is defined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22083141/4279).

---

If you want to see the output on the screen as soon as command prints them; you could inline `Tee`, [`copyfileobj()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c4155f460ae7bf0e816c5144fb2a99cedf5a31a5/Lib/shutil.py#L70-L76) and [use `os.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.read), to avoid reading the complete `length` before writing it to `stdout`:

```
chunks = []
with p.stdout:
    for chunk in iter(lambda: os.read(p.stdout.fileno(), 1 << 13), b''):
        getattr(sys.stdout, 'buffer', sys.stdout).write(chunk)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        chunks.append(chunk)
return p.wait(), b''.join(chunks)
```

To disable the internal block-buffering in the child process, you might try to [run it using `stdbuf` or pass pseudo-tty instead of the pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279).

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions! Will report back as soon as I test them out.

As for catch_stderr having no effect, sometimes I run commands that print to `stderr` instead of `stdout` (`dd` as an example). I will see if your code solves that as well. 

Thank you very much.

Comment: I can confirm that `preexec_fn` fixed the issue with the UnixBench. It finishes all the benchmarks successfully.


However, I couldn't make your version with `Tee`  to output in realtime (the way the original function worked) but I could modify my code to work. I still need to figure out a way around the potential deadlock issue you've pointed out.

Thanks again! You're the best!

Comment: Oh and I've noticed your update too late. Thanks for the implementation of real-time output. Will try that tonight! SO needs to implement "send a beer" button :)

Comment: @Anton: The code in the answer captures both stdout/stderr as your code does but without the risk of the deadlock. You could subscribe to the question feed (below on the right)